# What do I need for a script that detects which device or computer used to visit my website?

Tags: javascript, tracking

I simply want to use an AJAX mechanism to track how long a person has been on a web page and whether a logged in, registered user is using more than one device or computer to access that page at the same time.

Is there a way for javascript or jQuery to send a unique identifier for the device or computer at intervals back to the web server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a cookie with appropriate session information and read it with  with every AJAX request from the page.

from session_id , your web server will know for whom that session was started and continuous long living AJAX requests, in terms of COMET and not polling should continue to help you update a timestamp which you can maintain for the user per device and calculate thus how long he has been there.

How you implement it on the server side is totally up to you, use sessions and DB wisely!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by implementing some API in backend and read the client information (browser info and os info) and store that in your server for the analytics... are you can try http://www.google.com/analytics/ which is free for user.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do that on the client.
The javascript "navigator" object can help you to detect browser & os, but that's not enough.
Better way is to detect request IP on server side, but that's not covering all cases either.

Browser cannot supply you any unique device id. 
But creating a browser plugin will help (because plugin can detect MAC address).